# Regular Expression - Java not working

Tags: java, regex

I have a line of Java code

`System.out.println("...Somtime".matches("^[^a-zA-Z]"));`

Which returns false. Why? Can any one help?

Comment: because the whole string should match your expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String.matches("regex")
```

This method will match the regex against the WHOLE string. If the string matches regex, it will return `true` and `false` otherwise

```
System.out.println("...Somtime".matches("^[^a-zA-Z]{3}[a-zA-Z]+"));
```

here for three dots you are using {3} and this return `true`

```
System.out.println("Somtime".matches("^[^a-zA-Z]"));
```

it return `false`

Answer (score 5):

`String#matches` matches at both the ends, so your pattern should cover the complete string. And also you don't need to give those anchors `(Caret - ^)` at the beginning. It is implicit.

Now, since your first three characters matches - `[^a-zA-Z]`, while the later characters matches - `[a-zA-Z]`.

So, probably you want: -

```
"...Somtime".matches("[^a-zA-Z]{3}[a-zA-Z]+")
```